# Как избавиться от вечного цикла MeteorJS

Tags: node.js, meteor

Я думаю, что мой `while(true)` противоречит "философии" асинхронной модели, но честно говоря я не знаю как его можно убрать/заменить

```
parsesite:function(){
    this.unblock(); // делает метод не блокирующим, создавая новый Fiber
    var tmp = 0;
    var body = ((HTTP.call("GET","somedata.json")));
    while (true){
      parse = body.data[tmp];
      var postExist = Posts.findOne({applyUrl: parse.url});
      if (!postExist){
       //do something
       tmp++;
      }
      else return false;
    }
  },
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как поправить?

Comment: что он вообще выполняет?

Answer (score 1):

Вроде бы этот код такой же:

```
this.unblock();
var body = HTTP.call("GET", "somedata.json");
for (var tmp=0; Posts.findOne({applyUrl: body.data[tmp].url}); ++tmp);
return false;
```

Но вообще, что-то тут явно не то. Неужели нельзя как-то нормальнее?